# framer-motion: element stops animating when changing state the 3rd time

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

Whenever *addStory()* is called, it displays and animates text, but on the 3rd time it only displays the text and not animate it. I tried changing the text and when I hit *Ctrl S* it animated it. How do I keep animating them whenever they are shown? I've been trying to solve this problem since yesterday but could not find a solution.

> sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-smoke-nt0we?file=/src/components/Game.tsx

> ps: *addStory()* displays different text whenever it is called, so it should re-render and animate.

```
  const addStory = (newStory: string) => {
    setStory(
      <>
        {newStory === undefined ? (
          <span>{story}</span>
        ) : (
          <>
            {newStory.split('\n').map((str, index) => (
              <motion.p
                key={index}
                initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                transition={{ duration: 1 }}
              >
                {str.length > 1 && '=> '}
                {str}
              </motion.p>
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
```

> the *addStory()* function is called like this

```
const whichChoice = () => {
    if (choice === 'a1') {
      return mainStory.a1;
    } else if (choice === 'a2') {
      return mainStory.a2;
    } else if (choice === 'b1') {
      return mainStory.b1;
    } else if (choice === 'b2') {
      return mainStory.b2;
    } else if (choice === 'c1') {
      return mainStory.c1;
    } etc......

      else return;
};

  useEffect(() => {
    const narrate = whichChoice();

    addStory(narrate);
  }, [choice]);
```

> the *choice* is changed using *onClick* via *useState* hook

> the *mainStory.a1* etc, returns a string from an object. It looks like this:

```
export const mainStory: any = {
  a: '=> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor',
  a1: '\n Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.',
  a2: '\n nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat',
  b1: '\n Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit \n in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur \n Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident',
  b2: '\n sunt in culpa qui officia \n deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. \n Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus \n voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium'

  etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the duration property in `motion.p` indicates that the animation runs from 0secs to 1secs. You might be looking for `transition={{yoyo: 10}}`

**EDIT**

Just understood, that its not triggering on consecutive renders, it seems the react DOM tree gets updated with each state change, for this, Framer needs an `AnimatePresence` to inform framer that the tree has changed.

Reference : https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/

Comment: it seems to have the same behavior; it doesn't animate on the 3rd time.

Comment: Can you try the `AnimatePresence` ?

Comment: I wrapped the motion.p with <AnimatePresence></ AnimatePresence>, & still had the same behavior.

Comment: The AnimatePresence is supposed to be a single instance, so you should not wrap the `motion.p` but the parent component, like a provider, within which the addStory renders.

Comment: A codesandbox of this would be helpful in answering the question.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-smoke-nt0we?file=/src/components/Game.tsx , the css is messed up on code-sandbox but it shows the problem. I added the AnimatePresence in Story.tsx where it's being rendered.

Comment: I think the duration is being taken as a common entity for all the motion.p, I believe tracking the `story` value change, would help.

Comment: Any updates on this please? Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: Apologies got caught up in work stuff, not yet, it seems to be a nested animation issue with framer, it could be a DOM update issue as well. I tried reciprocating it, in a different piece of code, it worked, but not quite sure over here. Will try to look over it during the weekend.